# Visual Studio _MSC_VER versus Platform Toolset

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a VS 2010 C++/CLI project that I imported into VS 2015.  Because it links against some VS 2010 C++ libraries that I don't control, I need it to be compiled with the VS 2010 compiler.  When I imported the project to VS 2015, I told VS not to upgrade the project (don't remember the exact options, but the project now says "Project Name (Visual Studio 2010)" in Solution Explorer).  In the project properties, the Platform Toolset is listed as "Visual Studio 2010 (v100)":

[image: Visual Studio Project Properties window showing Visual Studio 2010 (v100) selected for Platform Toolset]

One of the libraries I'm using has a header with some ifdefs that show an error if `_MSC_VER` isn't one of the supported versions (Visual C++ 6.0-10.0).  That error is being generated for this project, and I've determined that the `_MSC_VER` showing up <del>during build</del> in Intellisense is 1900 (the default for VS 2015).

How do I get the project to build with the 2010 version of the C++ compiler (`_MSC_VER` 1600)?  Isn't that what the Platform Toolset option is supposed to control?

Comment: Make sure that the "Platform Toolset" is v100 for all projects.

Comment: @tambre, thanks.  I only have two C++ projects in my solution (the rest are C#), and both of the C++ projects have a "Platform Toolset" set to v100.

Comment: I would start procmon to see how MsBuild finds and starts cl.exe.

Comment: Interesting. It's possible that some things from the VS 2010 project files aren't interpreter correctly by VS15 unless upgraded to newer equivalents. Try upgrading the solution and then setting the platform toolset to v100.

Comment: I just realized that the error was coming from Intellisense, not the build.  Builds were actually working fine.  It's a minor bug in Visual Studio.  I've added an answer to help anyone else coming across this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I misunderstood what was going on in Visual Studio.  The build was actually working fine; the error being generated was coming from Intellisense.  There's a [known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/761812/msc-ver-does-not-reflect-selected-toolset-in-editor) in Visual Studio where Intellisense doesn't properly reflect the `_MSC_VER` specified by the project's selected Platform Toolset.  I'll leave the question up in case anyone else runs into this problem.